# Power BI: Google Ads: The Key didn't match any rows in the table

Tags: powerbi

I am consistently hitting this problem when moving between working mobile on my laptop and then returning to my desktop.

The file is identical as I just emailed it to myself.

Both the laptop and desktop are running the same version of Power BI.

I have read numerous articles about this being related to column name changes and problems with the datasource. But have been unable to track the problem.

At the moment i only have 2 datasources. Google Ads and Microsoft SQL Server. When i go to "Recent Sources" both open and allow me to navigate the data sources without problem.

Can anyone offer any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out i was logged into Google Ads connector with different username/password on each machine and the different users had different views of the data.

Causing the key problem